# Dagger + Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, dagger-2

We chose Dagger2 over spring as the dependency injection framework in one of storm applications. 
We also have a legacy spring MVC based application, that uses some of the code from the dagger project in a multi-project gradle setup.

The (simplified) project hierarchy looks like:

1. :dagger-core
2. :storm-dagger (depends on dagger-core)
3. :spring-ui (depends on dagger-core)

Since both spring and dagger have their own ways of bootstrapping the object graph, what is the best way to have #3 working together? Currently, we have an @Component factory class in spring-ui, which "provides" the dependencies from dagger-core. Both the factory and the provided classes are then defined as spring beans using spring's factory pattern (factory class as factory-bean using factory-method, and other provided classes as factory-method of factory-bean). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hello, Robbin. I have the similar situation. I would like integrate dagger2 with spring. If you have a time, could send me email to kasyanov.maxim@outlook.com, i have several questions. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, we have an @Component factory class in spring-ui, which "provides" the dependencies from dagger-core. Both the factory and the provided classes are then defined as spring beans using spring's factory pattern (factory class as factory-bean using factory-method, and other provided classes as factory-method of factory-bean).